# Usage of SqLite Query() parameters

Tags: android, sqlite

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor mCursor =db.query(TABLE_ACCOUNTS, new String[]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s}, null,null, null, null, null);
```

My question is:
Will this initialization allow to return ALL values in the db database & table?

As far as my project, it appears to only be returning NULL values. (No Error)
a = null,b = null,c = null

Detected some actual values when i manipulated with the 3rd parameter with a+"=?" and variations (which is now null).

Or could the prevention of actual values be something else? (assuming Adding Data to the DB works)

(Adding code)

```
public void addAccount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     Account account = new Account();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(id, account.getA()); // Contact Name
        values.put(a, account.getA()); // Contact Phone Number
        values.put(b, account.getB()); // Contact Phone Number
        values.put(c, account.getC());
...

        db.insert(TABLE_ACCOUNTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }
```

(Cursor code)

```
 if ( (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) ) {

            do {
                stringResult1 = 
                        "a: "+ mCursor.getString(0)+ "\n"
                     + "b: " + mCursor.getString(1) + "\n"
                     + "c: " + mCursor.getString(2) + "\n"
                     + "d: " + mCursor.getString(3) + "\n"
                     + "e: " + mCursor.getString(4) + "\n"
                     + "f: " + mCursor.getString(5) + "\n"
                     + "g: " + mCursor.getString(6) + "\n"
                     + "h: " + mCursor.getString(7) + "\n"
                     + "i " + mCursor.getString(8) + "\n"
                     + "j: " + mCursor.getString(9) + "\n"
                     + "k: " + mCursor.getString(10) + "\n"
                     + "l: " + mCursor.getString(11) + "\n"
                     + "m: " + mCursor.getString(12) + "\n"
                     + "n: " + mCursor.getString(13) + "\n"
                     + "o: " + mCursor.getString(14) + "\n"
                     + "p: " + mCursor.getString(15) + "\n"
                     + "q: " + mCursor.getString(16) + "\n"
                     + "r: " + mCursor.getString(17) + "\n"
                     + "s: " + mCursor.getString(18) + "\n";
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());


        // make sure to close the cursor
        mCursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: what are a,b,c,d....? are they string variables

Comment: Yes
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ACCOUNTS + "("
                + a + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + b + " TEXT,"
                + c+ " TEXT," + d + " TEXT,"+ e+ " TEXT," + f+ " TEXT,"+ g+ " TEXT," + h + " TEXT," + i+ " TEXT,"+ j+ " TEXT," + k+ " TEXT,"
                + l+ " TEXT," + m + " TEXT," + n+ " TEXT," + o+ " TEXT," + p+ " TEXT,"+ q +" TEXT, " + r+ " TEXT,"+ s+ " TEXT" + ");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

Comment: can you add the variable declaration code also?

Comment: private static final String a = "a";
private static final String b= "b";
private static final String c= "c";
and same goes for the rest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cursor mCursor =db.query(TABLE_ACCOUNTS, new String[]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s}, null,null, null, null, null);
```

Regarding above query.. the second parameter ie a String array is projection parameter means the columns that you want to be fetched in from db and fill it in cursor.

since if in the query the value of a,b,c,d,e... variables could be different that that of columns in db so there are no values exists in cursor for the requested column.

Hope that helps ! Thanks

Comment: Appreciate the thought relsell. 
Most examples are defining the elements and querying in this manner.
Besides, there was actual values prompted before manipulating the parameters.
I believe there is something else amiss.

Comment: Apparently the values of the tables were NULL even during creation/insert.
Sorted it out. Thanks for the help people!